# CSS not working with space

Tags: css

I have a problem with my code, I showed here as well:

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">123123123wgwe76gx7w6esldkfhxns7df</div>
```

When I put my class "test" with `width: 200px` and a string in div, having a space in the string will cause a line break.

Here's the code.

```
<div class="test">123123123wgwe76gx 7w6esldkfhxns7df</div>
```

Comment: Hi use `word-wrap: break-word` in your css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :)

```
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
```